# How to start playing with JDK7

Tags: java, java-7

Since i read that the early release of JDK7 was available for developers to play with i decided to have a look. About 5 minutes later after trying to play with some of the project coin features i realised that Eclipse does not support it yet.

So my question is what is the best way to start playing with JDK7? I assume that the good folk at Oracle and elsewhere are using an IDE to develope and test the new features or is is back to vi? Does netbeans provide support?

Comment: This is the 100000th question tagged "java"

Comment: Check out this article for the java 7 feature netbeans supports http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorJDK7

Comment: @irreputable.  Funny, but the main page says 99994.

Comment: Hey, what is wrong with using a text editor?  My first 5+ years of Java programming were done exclusively with a text editor (emacs).  Kids these days ... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the latest netbeans beta has support for JDK7 features.  [See here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=61952)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Netbeans beta is your answer.Netbeans 7 (beta 2 I think) has jdk7 support.

See this article http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=61952

Switch statement for strings! Can't wait!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.7.2 support JDK7. I have used it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA supports Java 7. (and 8 !? whatever that is)

And it is the best IDE.

Comment: In order to get a Java release out the door this year they split the previous planned release into two, hence Java 7 & Java 8 being fairly well defined. Press release here - http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/193190 ... or an interview with Language Architect Brian Goetz here :-http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/briangoetzchief-188795.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen